# Will augmented solders keep their previous rank when they become MEC troopers?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

When a solder is augmented and becomes a MEC trooper, they lose their old skills (except for the single trait based on what class they were before), but do they lose their rank as well? If I augment a Colonel, will I be able to select all seven new MEC Trooper abilities for them right away, or will they revert to Squaddie?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you maintain rank when you change class, allowing you to pick abilities up to your previous rank. You also maintain bonus Hitpoints, Will, and Aim; This means that augmenting a Sniper will result in a MEC with higher accuracy, but less health.

Once augmented, however, they will begin to use MEC progression instead (same as Heavy).